# How to get this font

Tags: fonts

I would like to typeset sanskrit in the font given at this page:
http://www.sanskritweb.net/sansdocs/gita-dev.pdf Devanagari typesetting uses a different font. Can anyone tell as to how i can use this font.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) What part exactly are you struggling with? Finding out the name of the font? Obtaining the font? Using it in your document? Please provide some more information, specify your question, and share what you've attempted so far.

Comment: @doncherry: I generally typeset Sanskrit using the "devanagari" processor. But I am interested in getting this font. After searching it seems that this font's name is "Sanskrit 2003".

Comment: Do you mean: http://www.sanskritweb.net/itrans/#SANS2003

Comment: @Marco: Exactly